# compare 2 columns from different tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables with same column in each.. Lets call it colors. How do I compare the two to show the unique colors in table B that are not in table A?

Answer (score 1):

```
select b.color
  from tbl1 b
 where not exists (select * from tbl2 a where b.color=a.color)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT b.color AS color FROM tableB b
LEFT JOIN tableA a ON a.color = b.color
WHERE a.color IS NULL;
```

Comment: This is correct, but while other database engines might have better optimized join implementations, SQLite [does all its joins as nested loop joins](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#table_order). So this query ends up being executed pretty mich the same way as RTKiwi's, while not being quite as as comprehensible.